# CSS: Why background-color breaks/removes the box-shadow?

Tags: html, css

I have a pretty simple div structure - tree boxes with middle box highlighted with box-shadow:

```css
.offerBox {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.obOffer {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.obOfferPrice {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #85AADD;
}

.obHiLight {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="offerBox">
  <div class="obOffer">
    <div class="obOfferTitle">Free</div>
    <div class="obOfferPrice">Free</div>
  </div>
  <div class="obOffer obHiLight">
    <div class="obOfferTitle">Title</div>
    <div class="obOfferPrice">$10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="obOffer">
    <div class="obOfferTitle">Title 2</div>
    <div class="obOfferPrice">$10</div>
  </div>
</div>​
```

​
One of the elements inside those boxes have a background-color property set. For some reasons this  background-color removes the box-shadow from the right and only from the right.

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Live Example of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/SqvUd/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You just need to add `z-index` and `position:relative;`
See the example:

```css
.offerBox { 
  border-radius: 6px; 
  width: 300px; 
  margin: 10px; 
}

.obOffer {
  position: relative; //  this
  width: 33%; 
  float: left;
  height: 100px; 
  text-align: center; 
  z-index: 0;
}

.obOfferPrice {
  padding: 10px;   
  color: white;
  background-color: #85AADD; 
}

.obHiLight {
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="offerBox">
  <div class="obOffer">
    <div class="obOfferTitle">Free</div>    
    <div class="obOfferPrice">Free</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="obOffer obHiLight">
    <div class="obOfferTitle">Title</div>    
    <div class="obOfferPrice">$10</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="obOffer">
    <div class="obOfferTitle">Title 2</div>    
    <div class="obOfferPrice">$10</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried z-index, but haven't thought about position:relative; It does fix the problem.

Comment: Using `position: relative;` solved this for me as well!  Much thanks, it was driving me crazy trying to solve this.

Comment: Any ideas on doing this for a table <tr> element, where position doesn't have any effect? In my use-case, I want a <tr> to have box shadow, but the rows also have a hover-effect that changes the background-color. When the rows around the box-shadowed row are hovered, they override the shadow on that side (top or bottom)

Comment: @ItJustWerks Just wondering if you found a solution to your issue? Im facing the exact same thing

Comment: What is the reason why `position: relative;` helps here?

Comment: @AndresEscobar each element has what we call a layout mode _(flow, positionned, flexbox, grid or table)_. Those modes specify witch properties are available and how they should be interpreted by the browser. By default, each element use the flow layout mode. This mode doesn't support z-index, but the positionned mode does. So we can switch from the flow mode to the positionned mode by setting the CSS property `position` to anything _(except static)_, and than we will have access to the z-index property.

Answer (score 8):

It has to do with the z-index of the items.  Try adding this to your existing css:

```
.obOffer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.obHiLight {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 100;
}​
```

Answer (score 3):

adding `.obHiLight{opacity:0.999}` creates a new stacking context for that element, which makes it appear above the others as well. This might work for tables too (didn't test :) . @ItJustWerks @brian-tacker