# Changing background-color of child removes box-shadow on parent

Tags: html, css, background-color, box-shadow

I am reading MDN Docs and a few articles, like [this one](https://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/), and [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587814/css-why-background-color-breaks-removes-the-box-shadow) after [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627053/box-shadow-and-100-fluid-width-issue) after [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47147711/not-getting-box-shadow-effect) among others, but I can't seem to find a way around my particular problem.

I have a card-type element that includes a full-width form of radio buttons. When a button is `:selected`, I add a class to the button's parent div to change it's `background-color`. Since the parent `div` is full-width, the repaint removes the `box-shadow` on the card where that particular `div` touches the edge.

I can't seem to find a solution, perhaps you can help.

Here is my code. How can I ensure that the change in `background-color` doesn't break my `box-shadow` effect? Or, is this just an issue with paints and I need to add some sort of custom `box-shadow` to my `.selected` class?

```js
$('.ClubSelect').click(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type=radio]')[0].click();
    $('.ClubSelect').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #422618;
    font-family: adobe-caslon-pro, serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div#SelectAClubLevel {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.select-card {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    max-width: 580px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}

.ClubSelect {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    background-color: #f5ddbc;
    height: 59px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.selected {
    background-color: #d49948;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.ClubSelect input,
.ClubLevelTitle,
.ClubLevelAmt {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #422618;
}

.ClubLevelTitle {
    font-family: freight-sans-pro, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-variant-numeric: lining-nums;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "lnum";
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "lnum";
    font-feature-settings: "lnum";
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.ClubSelect input {
    margin: 12px 5px 12px 20px;
    width: 1.4rem;
    height: 1.4rem;
}

.ClubLevelAmt {
    font-family: freight-sans-pro, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-variant-numeric: lining-nums;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "lnum";
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "lnum";
    font-feature-settings: "lnum";
    font-size: 2rem;
    width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="SelectAClubLevel">
    <h3>Please select a Monthly Giving Level</h3>
    <div class="select-card">
    
        <div id="club-84" class="ClubSelect LowerClub">
            <input ID="CLUB_LEVEL_1000" type="radio" value="84.00" name="clubselect" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
            <div class="ClubLevelAmt"><span>$84</span>/month</div>
            <div class="ClubLevelTitle">1000&nbsp;Club</div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="club-209" class="ClubSelect LowerClub">
            <input ID="CLUB_LEVEL_2500" type='radio' value="209.00" name="clubselect" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
            <div class="ClubLevelAmt"><span>$209</span>/month</div>
            <div class="ClubLevelTitle">2500&nbsp;Club</div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="club-417" class="ClubSelect LowerClub">
            <input ID="CLUB_LEVEL_FOUNDERS" type='radio' value="417.00" name="clubselect" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
            <div class="ClubLevelAmt"><span>$417</span>/month</div>
            <div class="ClubLevelTitle">Founder's Club</div>
        </div>

        <div id="club-834" class="ClubSelect UpperClub">
            <input ID="CLUB_LEVEL_CHAIRMANS" type='radio' value="834.00" name="clubselect" onclick="handleClick(this)" />
            <div class="ClubLevelAmt"><span>$834</span>/month</div>
            <div class="ClubLevelTitle">Chairman's Circle</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be removing the box shadow at all. What it does seem to be doing, though, is making the box shadow harder to see due to decrease in contrast of colors. Increase the opacity on your box shadow and you'll see it remains in tact and easily seen.

Comment: Ok. You are right. So because my opacity is so light on the shadow, and given the contrast with the background color, it's an optical illusion. I've been going nuts for an hour on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a painting effect cos it doesn't break your box-shadow

Comment: From what I can tell, this is correct.  If you change the selected color to something like a very light grey, you can still see the shadow.  Also, if you extend the shadow to the right, it's still there on click.